# Using sleep() and GetAsyncKeyState functions separately

Tags: c, sleep

I am trying to make something like a simple tetris game program in C and for speed of falling I am using `sleep()` but it also delays the `GetAsyncKeyState()` function so that I can use it only once per 1 falling block. Can anyone explain how to use this two separately?

Answer (score 0):

You should not sleep in the gui thread! This blocks any GUI activity. Just use timer to update the state of the game every 1 second or how often you need.

Comment: Thank you, I should go more into time functions then.